# What are the odds of 5 different digits being arranged in descending order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem, I personally think the answer is 1/32 because every other number that's picked can be either more or less than the number before therefore I think the answer is 1/2^5.

Also would the odds of  3 different letters being in alphabetic order be the same as the question above? I think they would be less, because the problem is handled in the same way the first is so the odds are 1/2^3 = 1/8

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: there are $5!$ ways to order them, so if you suppose all orders are equally likely....

Comment: For your three letter case, there are $3!=6$ permutations, so the answer is $\frac 16$.

Comment: By the way, the answer $\frac1{2^3}$ for three letters seems to assume that there are three letters in the result that each might have come before or after the previously chosen letter in alphabetical order. What three letters are those? The first letter cannot be one of them, since there is no previously chosen letter!